# Using dplyr first function but ignoring a particular character

Tags: r, dplyr

I wish to add the first feature in the following dataset in a new column

```
 mydf <- data.frame (customer= c(1,2,1,2,2,1,1) , feature =c("other", "a", "b", "c", "other","b", "c"))

    customer feature
1        1   other
2        2       a
3        1       b
4        2       c
5        2   other
6        1       b
7        1       c
```

by using `dplyr`. However, I wish to my code ignore the "other" feature in the data set and choose the first one after "other".

so the following code is not sufficient:

```
library (dplyr)    
new <- mydf %>%
  group_by(customer) %>%
  mutate(firstfeature = first(feature))
```

How can I ignore "other" so that I reach the following ideal output:

```
    customer   feature   firstfeature

1        1   other            b
2        2       a            a
3        1       b            b
4        2       c            a
5        2   other            a
6        1       b            b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr` we can group by `customer` and take the first `feature` for every group.

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
   group_by(customer) %>%
   mutate(firstfeature = feature[feature != "other"][1])


#  customer feature firstfeature
#     <dbl>   <chr>        <chr>
#1        1   other            b
#2        2       a            a
#3        1       b            b
#4        2       c            a
#5        2   other            a
#6        1       b            b
#7        1       c            b
```

---

Similarly we can also do this with base R `ave`

```
mydf$firstfeature <- ave(mydf$feature, mydf$customer, 
                                         FUN= function(x) x[x!= "other"][1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, firstfeature := feature[feature != "other"][1], customer]
```